# Chrome support for input:checked+label?

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-selectors

Has anyone else noticed an issue with Chrome's support of this?

```
input:checked+label
```

It works fine on with the first radio set, but fails on the second.  See my js bin...

http://jsbin.com/egutap/2/edit

**UPDATE:** Updated jsbin link as I had a bug, but still seeing same issue.

Comment: It works just fine for me on `24.0.1312.57 m`.

Comment: Maybe its a beta thing.  I'm using Version 25.0.1364.58 beta-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a version specific bug with Version 25.0.1364.58 beta-m.  Seems to be resolved in the latest version.